# `HashMap::get_mut` leading to "returns reference to local value", any efficient work-around?

Tags: rust, hashmap

There have been a fair number of questions around this, and the solution is mostly "use `Entry`".

However this is an issue because `HashMap::entry()` requires an owned value meaning possibly expensive copies / allocations even when the key is already present and we just want to update the value in-place, hence the use of `get_mut`. However the use of `get_mut` on a reference to a local leads rustc to assume that said reference gets stored into the hashmap, and [thus that returning the hashmap is an error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d39d274bb53ee49b977266ded72b255):

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn get_string() -> String { String::from("xxxxxxx") }
fn foo() -> HashMap<Cow<'static, str>, usize> {
    let mut v = HashMap::new();

    // stand-in for "get a string slice as key",
    // real case is getting a String from an 
    // mpsc and the key being a segment of that string
    let s = get_string();
    // stand-in for a structure which contains an `Option<Cow>`
    let k = Cow::from(&s[2..3]);

    // because of get_mut, `&s` is apparently considered to be stored in `v`?
    if let Some(e) = v.get_mut(&k) {
        *e += 1;
    } else {
        v.insert(Cow::from(k.into_owned()), 0);
    }

    v
}
```

Note that the manipulations at lines 9~13 are there to clarify the point of the pattern, but [`get_mut` alone is sufficient to trigger the issue](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2553bd89966e6fd3c513083f8713772c)

Is there a way around without the efficiency hit, or is an eager allocation the only way? (note: because this is a static issue, dynamic gates like `contains_key` or `get` obviously don't do anything).

Comment: There is not really sense to use Cow here also you should prefer entry, or in your case entry_raw

Comment: @Stargateur as noted in the comments, `Cow` serves as a stand-in for a more complicated structure (which contains a Cow). I guess `raw_entry_mut` might work but it requires nightly still...

Comment: @Stargateur and apparently [it's being rejected](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56167#issuecomment-810457405) anyway so building upon it seems like a poor idea.

Comment: For even more clarity I'm trying to update code from strings (which are unstructured and for efficiency's sake have limited flexibility) to richer enums-with-strings-as-associated-data… and of course because of the semantics of Borrow you can't really create relations between non-trivial structures where one's the borrow of the other (or so I understand) since `Borrowed` is always returned by reference.

Comment: Well, you could own in Cow directly, but then it may lose the purpouse of Cow itself?  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=337d756b3c8a4f9b12ed0058e83daa2b

Comment: @Netwave yep that's not super useful. But anyway in re-reading the code for the nth time I just realised I have `String`s which I am *not* reusing (in lots of other loops they're buffers to read into but not in this specific case) so instead of slicing I could probably mess around with `replace_with` and `truncate` in order to operate entirely within the existing string, and thus *have* an owned string but not need to create new allocations. So while the question remains, I can probably work around the issue in my specific case.

Comment: without a better context we can't help you much, as I said, the only thing come to my mind looking your code is that it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut), `HashSet::get_mut()` requires a value of type `&Q` such that the key of the hash implements `Borrow<Q>`.

The key of your hash is `Cow<'static, str>`, that [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#impl-Borrow%3CB%3E) `Borrow<str>`. This means that you can use either a `&Cow<'static, str>` or a `&str`. But you are passing a `&Cow<'local, str>` for some `'local` lifetime. The compiler tries to match that `'local` with `'static` and issues a somewhat confusing error message about lifetimes.

The solution is actually easy, because you can get an `&str` from the `Cow` either calling `k.as_ref()` or doing `&*k`, and the lifetime of the `&str` is unrestricted: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=77acfd1f423a7c350d561ac6fe36e9b3))

```
let k = Cow::from(&s[2..3]);
if let Some(e) = v.get_mut(k.as_ref()) { /* ...*/ }
```